# Dependent types in typescript - determine type via the property name type

Tags: typescript, dependent-type

I was trying to make the types dependent on the type of the passed argument.
A contrived example is:

```js
type NS = "num" | "str"
type Data<T extends NS> = T extends "num" ? number : string
type Func<T extends NS> = (x: Data<T>) => Data<T>
type Funcs = {[T in NS]: Func<T>}
type Obj = {[T in NS]: Data<T>}
const funcs: Funcs = {
  num: (x) => x * 2,
  str: (x) => x + x
}

function useFunc<T extends NS>(ns: T, obj: Obj): Data<T> {
  const f = funcs[ns]
  const x = obj[ns]
  return f(x)
}
```

The problem is that `f(x)` has type `number | string` rather than `Data<T>`, that seems caused by `f` having type `Funcs[T]` rather than `Func<T>`. `x` also has type `Obj[T]` rather than `Data<T>`.

So typescript cannot infer that `Funcs[T]` and `Func<T>` are the same, and `Obj[T]` and `Data<T>` are the same, even though that is how `Funcs` and `Obj` are defined...

I can make it work by typecasting everything, but it defeats the purpose of using types:

```js
function useFunc<T extends NS>(ns: T, obj: Obj): Data<T> {
  const f = funcs[ns] as Func<T>
  const x = obj[ns] as unknown as Data<T>
  // note the double-cast as Obj[T] and Data<T> "do not sufficiently overlap"
  return f(x)
}
```

Is there a way to make it work in typescript?

EDIT:

I know that it can be made work in this way, that works for the call sites, but pointless from code re-use point of view - combining the same logic on different types was the actual motivation to do it, and in this way it is simply repeated.

```js
function useFunc<T extends NS>(ns: T, obj: Obj): Data<T>
function useFunc(ns: NS, obj: Obj): Data<NS> {
  if (ns === "num") {
    const f = funcs[ns]
    const x = obj[ns]
    return f(x)
  }

  const f = funcs[ns]
  const x = obj[ns]
  return f(x)
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this repetition without losing type safety?

Comment: Why you pass to ```useFunc``` argument ```obj``` which has type ```Obj```? It can be simplified to ```Data<T>```.

Comment: Not sure I understand. `Data<T>` is the type of properties in the object, both the property and the function is selected by `ns` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you trying to call `f` function inside `useFunc` when TS infer `f` signature as `(x: never) => string | numer`. This signature is not compatible with every signature inside `funcs` object.

Also, as I said signature `useFunc<T extends NS>(ns: T, obj: Obj): Data<T>` should be simplified, or even it's better to say corrected, to `useFunc<T extends NS>(ns: T, obj: Data<T>): Data<T>`. That's because TS should know the type of data you will pass to `f` to be able to make type checking. Also, another reason requires the above modification is that `useFunc` function call available only with `ns` equal to `"num"` or `"str"`, but not simultaneously. Because of the above, `obj` parameter type will be `Data<"num">` or `Data<"str">`. Consequently, it's wrong to type it as `Obj`.

Possible solution with minimal changes will be:

```
function useFunc<T extends NS>(ns: T, arg: Data<T>): Data<T> {
  const f = funcs[ns]
  return (f as Func<T>)(arg)
}
```

Comment: I understand that what you suggest would work. But I need to pass the whole object that contains two properties, not the property. Both the property and the function should be chosen based on `ns` parameter. I need to infer all types based on the type of `ns` parameter.

Comment: The question can be framed differently - the above is a valid JavaScript code, and quite a common pattern for code re-use in JS - pass string that is used as property/method selector across multiple objects. Can this pattern can be expressed in a type-safe way in Typescript without repeating the code?

Comment: And you still have to use type cast for `f` btw that defeats the point of using types...

Comment: I think the TS compiler isn't smart enough to make such assumptions. So, completely avoid type asserts inside your function is impossible.